# Pandas groupby and rolling returning different results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I'm not sure if this has been asked before, at least I couldn't find it then.

I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(50,2),columns=list('AB'),index=pd.date_range('20180101 9:01:00',freq='s',periods=50))
```

I want to group this dataframe into groups of 5 seconds each and calculate the mean of those groups.

This can be done either with groupby:

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s')).mean()
```

Or using rolling, calculating the mean and then taking every 5th value from this:

```
df2 = df.rolling(5).mean()[::5]
```

However, this is not returning the same result:

```
df1 == df2
Out[439]: 
                         A      B
2018-01-01 09:01:00  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:05  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:10  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:15  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:20  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:25  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:30  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:35  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:40  False  False
2018-01-01 09:01:45  False  False
```

Why is this not returning the same result? And how do I have to change the rolling mean, to make it equal to the groupby approach? I tried already the different parameters for 'closed', but this didn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Index alignment is different in the two dataframes.  And, your indexing of df2 is off.

```
df1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='5s')).mean() 
print(df1.head())

                            A         B
2018-01-01 09:01:00  0.354461  0.272654
2018-01-01 09:01:05 -0.191869  0.106352
2018-01-01 09:01:10 -0.519830  0.194780
2018-01-01 09:01:15  0.360278  0.753964
2018-01-01 09:01:20 -0.085151 -1.266094
```

and

```
df2 = (df.rolling(5).mean())[4::5]
print(df2.head())

                            A         B
2018-01-01 09:01:04  0.354461  0.272654
2018-01-01 09:01:09 -0.191869  0.106352
2018-01-01 09:01:14 -0.519830  0.194780
2018-01-01 09:01:19  0.360278  0.753964
2018-01-01 09:01:24 -0.085151 -1.266094
```

Now, to compare since pandas does mostly all operations with intrinsic data alignment using indexes, we will convert those dataframes to numpy arrays and compare. And, because we are dealing with floats, let's use `np.isclose`:

```
np.isclose(df1.head().values,df2.head().values)

array([[ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Glad, I could help Frank.  Happy coding.